# Search button, not case sensitive accepting special characters

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, search, richtextbox

I have a search button "find next" that searches in a `RichTextBox`, the only problem is, when I search for "[e]" then it will mark any "e" in the `RichTextBox`. And if I search for "[", then the program will crash. Here is my code:

```
private void downBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SearchWord = textBox1.Text;
    if (SearchWord.Length > 0)
    {
        if (SearchWord != prevWord)
        {
            index = 0;
            prevWord = SearchWord;
        }

        Regex reg = new Regex(SearchWord, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (Match find in reg.Matches(richTextBox1.Text))
        {
            if (find.Index >= index)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(find.Index, find.Length);
                richTextBox1.Focus();
                index = find.Index + find.Length;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping your search term so that it does not include characters used by regular expressions.

Use the [Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do so.

So you could change your code to:

```
string escapedSearchTerm = Regex.Escape(SearchWord)
Regex reg = new Regex(escapedSearchTerm, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```